# Stop Word removal with RNNs

Tags: classification, text-mining, recurrent-neural-network

Is it required or encouraged to remove stop words from documents when using Recurrent Neural Networks for Text Classification?

To my understanding RNNs are able to "understand" words in a context and I'm wondering if I remove too much of that context by removing stop words.